# iOS Webkit detect swipe and drag events on scrolling element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `UIWebView` containing a `<ul>` with `overflow:scroll` and `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` set.

When a user interacts with the element and the `touchend` event fires I want to know if this is the end of a drag/pan or the beginning of momentum scroll due to a swipe.

Is this possible?

The reason I want this is so that when the drag or momentum scroll has finished, I can line up an `<li>` at a certain point.

Basic setup without solution in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/benwise/pen/oxQGYO).

I tried using Hammer js to detect swipe and pan gestures, but this stops momentum scrolling from occurring on the element as far as I can tell.

Comment: please post your code ,it will be useful to recognize your question

Comment: thx @willie I expanded my question